# How does the O(n sqrt(n)) algorithm work that lists all possible sums given an array of numbers?

Tags: algorithm

I came across one algorithm problem in the book Competitive programming handbook https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf: Integer partitions, Knapsack.

The problem is: Given an array of integers whose sum is *n*. Output all possible sums that can be formed by using a subset of integers.

The dynamic programming solution is understandable. Define `dp(x,k)` as a bool function that is true when we can use the first `k` numbers to sum up to `x`, and false otherwise. Then `dp(x,k) = dp(x,k-1) | dp(x-A[k],k-1)`. The complexity is O(n^2).

However, the book described another solution that leverages one fact that the number of distinct numbers in the array is O(sqrt (n)), and then mentioned a solution by grouping similar numbers together. How does it work? The book seems hard to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the author should have been more explicit. My reconstruction is that, given an element *a* and an (*n*+1)-element bit array indicating which sums can be made by subsets of the previously considered elements, we can calculate in linear time the minimum number of copies of *a* that we need to make a particular sum, then threshold by how many copies of *a* we actually have. Python implementation below.

```py
import collections
import math


def subset_sums(lst):
    n = sum(lst)
    dp = [False] * (n + 1)
    dp[0] = True
    for a, count in collections.Counter(lst).items():
        dp = [min_count <= count for min_count in min_counts(dp, a)]
    return {x for (x, dp_x) in enumerate(dp) if dp_x}


def min_counts(dp, a):
    dp = [(0 if dp_x else math.inf) for dp_x in dp]
    for x in range(a, len(dp)):
        dp[x] = min(dp[x], dp[x - a] + 1)
    return dp


def baseline_subset_sums(lst):
    n = sum(lst)
    dp = [False] * (n + 1)
    dp[0] = True
    for a in lst:
        for x in range(len(dp) - 1, a - 1, -1):
            dp[x] = dp[x] or dp[x - a]
    return {x for (x, dp_x) in enumerate(dp) if dp_x}


import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for rep in range(100000):
        rand_lst = [random.randrange(20) for i in range(random.randrange(20))]
        assert subset_sums(rand_lst) == baseline_subset_sums(rand_lst), rand_lst
```

Comment: Nice solution. One minor issue: it runs in python3 not python2 due to math.inf

Comment: @DachuanHuang you can substitute `float("inf")`.

Comment: @DachuanHuang: Python 2 was discontinued on January 1, 2020 after more than a decade of trying to extirpate it. Nothing should support it anymore. https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/